# Flutter How to create a Curved Slider?

Tags: flutter, slider, shapes

[image]

This is an image I found on Stackoverflow only and I want a Slider shaped like this. I tried packages like `sleek_circular_slider` and other packages but I was not able to create this shape.

I can create this shape in CustomPainter and when I tried to use `SliderTrackShape` to customize the SLider Shape it didn't worked.

```
class CustomSlider extends SliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
     RenderBox? parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
     SliderThemeData? sliderTheme,
     bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
  }) {
    final double thumbWidth =
        sliderTheme!.thumbShape!.getPreferredSize(true, isDiscrete!).width;
    final double? trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    assert(thumbWidth >= 0);
    assert(trackHeight! >= 0);
    assert(parentBox!.size.width >= thumbWidth);
    assert(parentBox!.size.height >= trackHeight!);

    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + thumbWidth / 2;
    final double trackTop =
        offset.dy + (parentBox!.size.height - trackHeight!) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - thumbWidth;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset offset, {
         RenderBox? parentBox,
         SliderThemeData? sliderTheme,
         Animation<double>? enableAnimation,
         TextDirection? textDirection,
         Offset? thumbCenter,
         bool? isDiscrete,
         bool? isEnabled,
      }) {
    if (sliderTheme!.trackHeight == 0) {
      return;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );

    final Paint fillPaint = Paint()
      ..color = sliderTheme.activeTrackColor!
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Paint borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final pathSegment = Path()
    ..moveTo(0, 2500)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(250 / 2, 250, 250, 250 / 2);
      
    context.canvas.drawPath(pathSegment, fillPaint);
    
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
```

This code renders just the thumb shape and no slider when I use this widget inside `tracakShape` for SliderTheme. But when I use similar code for CustomShape I am able to create this shape successfully like this :

```
class CustomSlider extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Color(0xff84CADE);
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 4.0;



    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

So I guess my question is how can I render this shape that I am succesfully rendering when I am extending from `SliderTrackShape` as I am unable to do so when trying to extend from SliderTrackShape class and create this shape.

Comment: How you will increase the slider value,  is it Ok to take extra space for height?

Comment: Yeah that's fine.

Comment: any update on this? I'm facing similar issue with more complex track.